# Exclude a particular nested directory from ls --ignore

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I need to list all the directories inside a directory called app.
The directory list looks like

```
app/frontend
app/authservice
app/mailservice
...............
...............
```

I want to list all the directories inside app directory except `app/frontend` from the root directory.

I managed to get the required output using `grep -v` command

```
ls -d /app/packages/*/ | grep -v packages/frontend/
```

but i would like to get the same out put by using `--ignore` in ls command.

Comment: If this is for a script, you should [avoid `ls` in the first place](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls --ignore` is for implied entries such as when listing a directory's contents without `-d`, or in a recursive listing with `ls -R`. It doesn't work on entries that are passed on the command-line, which you've done with `/app/packages/*/`. Importantly, it's the shell that expands the `*` glob, not `ls`, so as far as `ls` is concerned the `frontend` directory is explicitly written out.

You could use shell features to omit a particular directory. This extended glob will list all directories except `frontend`:

```
ls -d /app/packages/!(frontend)/
```

(In a script you will need `shopt -s extglob`. Extended globs are usually enabled by default in interactive shells but disabled in scripts.)